# Am I forced to Use Apple In-App Purchase API

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

So the review team said this:

> We noticed that your app or its metadata enables the purchase of content, services, or functionality in the app by means other than the in-app purchase API, which is not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> Specifically, subscriptions to employee management can be purchased by means other than the in-app purchase API.

I was using the PayPal SDK and I'm not a big fan of using apples in-app payment system. Are they forcing me to use it anyway in order to get a cut? The app works as a free trail for 2 weeks, but if I can avoid using the apples in-app purchase API, I could give users a permanent free account feature.

There is also a web-version and an android version that uses PayPal.

Comment: "Are they forcing me to use it anyway in order to get a cut" Yes they are.

Answer (score 1):

If you are paying a digital content with the subscriptions , then yes you won't be able to pass review and distribute your app without IAP , the policy in android is different this is clearly stated here

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

in **3. Business** section

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, every single app uploaded to the appstore is going to get a cut from apple if you have in-app purchases as a feature.

I think it remains 30-70 and there's no way to avoid this, in fact this is the reason you can't buy a book directly from the Amazon app, nor even provide a link to buy it. You need to manually go to the browser, and buy it there. Not good, poor user experience but otherwise Apple would be doing tons of money on the shoulders of Amazon...

Comment: As a developer you are free to sell aluminum siding, or print books, or yoga classes through your own payment processing service in your app with Apple's blessings.  Apple only restricts the sale of electronic goods or services to their in-app-purchase protocol (and yes, get their 30% cut).  Those goods might include new levels for a game app, new languages in a translation app, new images or music for a meditation app; anything delivered electronically through the app.